# DirectXMathConvert.inl assertion failure (DirectXMathConvert.inl line 704)

Tags: visual-c++, assert, directxmath

Would someone be kind enough to translate me this piece of code to human readable ?

```
|704| assert(((uintptr_t)pSource & 0xF) == 0);
```

Basically this assertion fails in my program, but not 100% of the time (without I recompile anything) which is rather strange.

The complete `XMLoadFloat4A` function being (line #697 - DirectXMathConvert.inl) :

```
|697| _Use_decl_annotations_
|698| inline XMVECTOR XM_CALLCONV XMLoadFloat4A
|699| (
|700|     const XMFLOAT4A* pSource
|701| )
|702| {
|703|     assert(pSource);
|704|     assert(((uintptr_t)pSource & 0xF) == 0);
|705| #if defined(_XM_NO_INTRINSICS_)
|706|     XMVECTOR V;
|707|     V.vector4_f32[0] = pSource->x;
|708|     V.vector4_f32[1] = pSource->y;
|709|     V.vector4_f32[2] = pSource->z;
|710|     V.vector4_f32[3] = pSource->w;
|711|     return V;
|712| #elif defined(_XM_ARM_NEON_INTRINSICS_)
|713|     return vld1q_f32_ex( reinterpret_cast<const float*>(pSource), 128 );
|714| #elif defined(_XM_SSE_INTRINSICS_)
|715|     return _mm_load_ps( &pSource->x );
|716| #endif
|717| }
```

Use cases :

```
// Convert an XMFLOAT4A to XMVECTOR
XMVECTOR getXMVECTORfromXMFLOAT4A(const XMFLOAT4A& v) {
    return XMLoadFloat4A(&v);
}
XMVECTOR foo = getXMVECTORfromXMFLOAT4A(XMFLOAT4A(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0));

// Transform XMFLOAT4A with XMMATRIX
XMFLOAT4A XMFloat4Transform(const XMFLOAT4A& v, const XMMATRIX& m) {
    XMVECTOR vec = XMLoadFloat4A(&v);
    XMVECTOR rot = XMVector4Transform(vec, m);
    XMFLOAT4A result;
    XMStoreFloat4A(&result, rot);
    return result;
}
XMMATRIX m = XMMatrixLookAtLH(...);
XMFLOAT4A foo (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0);
XMFLOAT4A bar = XMFloat4Transform(foo, m);
```

Why does this asserstion fail ? And why not 100% of the time ?

Comment: Which Version of MSVC?

Comment: You may want to take a look at the [SimpleMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SimpleMath) wrapper for DirectXMath in the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK). It makes DirectXMath a little more forgiving of stuff like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.reference.xmfloat4a(v=vs.85).aspx) says `XMFLOAT4A` "Describes an XMFLOAT4 structure aligned on a 16-byte boundary."

That is what the `assert` is checking. It is not sufficient for `XMLoadFloat4A` to have an `XMFLOAT4`, which only needs to be aligned for ist float members (8 bytes), it needs a `XMFLOAT4A` which is aligned on 16 byte boundary. This might be for performance reasons or because the intrinsics require it.

Normally `XMFLOAT4A` is marked with `__declspec(align(16))`, so the compiler knows that he must align this struct to 16 bytes. In your case you could check the declaration of `XMFLOAT4A`. I suggest using [compiler switch `/EP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/becb7sys.aspx) which writes out a file after preprocessor phase and before the compiler starts. That might help you detect if some macro messes with your `XMFLOAT4A` declaration.

You should also check which exact call fails.

Also: MSDN has an [article on __declspec(align(#))](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/83ythb65(v=VS.120).aspx). This says that if you pass a an `XMFLOAT4A` by value to a function then you lose alignment. In your code I only see pass by reference, but this is still an interesting point to keep in mind.

Comment: How can I make sure my `XMFLOAT4A` is always aligned then ? Doc says it should be but the assert still fails. Might as well convert all my `XMFLOAT4A` to `XMFLOAT4`.

Comment: `XMFLOAT4A` declaration is `__declspec(align(16)) struct XMFLOAT4A : public XMFLOAT4 {...}` - I don't see anything messing with it anywhere else in the preprocessor file. Off to using `XMFLOAT4` instead I guess =)

Comment: @PinkTurtle I added some comments to the answer. Maybe you want to check.

Comment: Yes I carefully checked all my XMFLOAT4A's are passed by reference. Actually the compiler would refuse to compile for a 'by copy' XMFLOAT4A argument. I went for plain XMFLOAT4 instead.

Comment: The compiler will let you do 'by copy' of 16-byte aligned data when building for x64.